# Hacker (Multiple IP's) attacking one page (lib.php) with a variable attached, what to do?

Tags: .htaccess, analytics, spam-prevention

I have in my main website root the file...

lib.php

So hackers keeps hitting my website with different IP addresses, different OS, different everything. The page is redirected to our 404 error page, and this 404 error page tracks visitors using standard visitor tracking analytics do allow us to see problems as they may arise.

Below is an example of the landing pages as shown in analytics by the hackers, except that I get about 200 hits per hour. Each link is a bit different as they are using a variable to set as a page url to goto.

```
mysite.com/lib.php?id=zh%2F78jQrm3qLoE53KZd2vBHtPFaYHTOvBijvL2NNWYE%3D
mysite.com/lib.php?id=WY%2FfNHaB2OBcAH0TcsAEPrmFy1uGMHgxmiWVqT2M6Wk%VD
mysite.com/lib.php?id=WY%2FfNHaB2OBcAH0TcsAEPrmFy1uGMHgxmiWVqJHGEWk%T%
mysite.com/lib.php?id=JY%2FfNHaB2OBcAH0TcsAEPrmFy1uGMHgxmiWVqT2MFGk%BD
```

I do not think I even need the file http://www.mysite.com/lib.php
Should I need it? When I visit mysite.com/lib.php it is redirected to my custom 404 page.

How can I stop this best? I am thinking by using .htaccess, but not sure the best setup?

Comment: Since these automated requests are not being successful at what they are trying to do, .htaccess or mod_security rules blocking them is unnecessary.

Comment: They are successful as they keep driving my analytics numbers way way up due to hitting the 404 error page, need it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably part of the Asprox botnet.
http://rebsnippets.blogspot.cz/asprox

Key thing is to change your password and stop using FTP protocol to access your privileged accounts.